# cv2/imagick process mixed 8 and 24 bit images

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, imagick

Due to some bug I have around 1000 tif images which are mixed 24 and 8 bit Images. Now im trying to read them with cv2. Is there any way to do this? So far I tried to convert all pictures to .png using Imagick, but when I use the following command:

```
imagick convert Answer1.tif Answer1.png
```

It only works for some pictures, the 24bit one turn into false color, where white is pink.
How can I convert everything to the same standart/read the mixed ones in Python?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer without having access to some of your images.

Comment: try `imagick convert Answer1.tif PNG24:Answer1.png` which will make them all 24-bits. But your syntax does not seem to me to be proper Imagick syntax.